# Sql Server: Convert months in calendar year to months in fiscal year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, calendar

I have a unique problem that I simply cannot wrap my head around.

So I am in SQL Server 2005 and I am given the following data to work with:

1. FISCAL_YEAR_START_MONTH INT (first month in a fiscal year)
2. COUNT_START_MONTH INT (the first month that we need to start from
3. TOTAL_MONTHS
4. YEAR[1-6]_MONTHS - this is the number of months per calendar year

I need to distribute the months among 6 fiscal years + leftovers

So for example:

```
FISCAL_YEAR_START_MONTH = 7
COUNT_START_MONTH = 9
TOTAL_MONTHS = 36
YEAR1_MONTHS = 4
YEAR2_MONTHS = 12
YEAR3_MONTHS = 12
YEAR4_MONTHS = 8
```

Should output

```
YEAR1_MONTHS YEAR2_MONTHS YEAR3_MONTHS YEAR4_MONTHS YEAR5_MONTHS YEAR6_MONTHS LEFTOVER
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ----------
10           12           12           2            0            0            0
```

I just can't solve this problem in sql. It's easy to see where months should distribute on a case by case as a human, but I can't turn this into an algorithm.

I tried calculating dates for each year, and keeping a running count of how many months I have left, neither solved my problem.,

Any solution, even one specific to the above example (but ideally a general one) will be really really helpful!

EDIT: fixed the rollover issue, seems like I received bad data

EDIT2: Another example, a simple one:

```
FISCAL_YEAR_START_MONTH = 7
COUNT_START_MONTH = 5
TOTAL_MONTHS = 14
YEAR1_MONTHS = 8
YEAR2_MONTHS = 6
```

Should output

```
YEAR1_MONTHS YEAR2_MONTHS YEAR3_MONTHS YEAR4_MONTHS YEAR5_MONTHS YEAR6_MONTHS LEFTOVER
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ----------
2           12            0            0            0            0            0
```

Comment: I'm still unclear what `FISCAL_YEAR_START_MONTH` and `COUNT_START_MONTH` mean. and what happned to `YEAR1_MONTHS = 4`

Comment: @VladimirOselsky Wondered the same, but I think it's explained by: "Since the count start month starts after the year has changed so it should rollover to the next year."

Comment: @GoatCO THat's it since the count start month is greater than fiscal year start month it rolls over

Comment: could you show another example set to help us understand the logic.

Comment: @GoatCO I changed the example above to forget about the rollover. Seems like I received some bad data and passed it on to StackOverflow. So now it should be more clear I hope. If I need to get another example I can

Comment: can explain exactly what `YEAR1_MONTHS = 4` and the rest mean?

Comment: @VladimirOselsky YEAR1_MONTHS = 4 means that there are 4 calendar months in Year 1. It really is a means to back into the COUNT_START_MONTH in the event it is not given because if there are 4 months in year1 we assume those to be the LAST 4 months in year1

Comment: So output of `YEAR1_MONTHS` `YEAR2_MONTHS` is for number of fiscal month in that year?

Comment: Yea I intend to use them as outputs in this table valued function so i dont have to recreate variables.

Comment: I have found a solution to the problem. Certainly not elegant but solves this problem. I will post it for others to critique or come up with better ideas later on I hope

Comment: Ah.  I missed the previous comment.  Not sure if I posted before or after you found your solution.  BTW, what happens if `FISCAL_YEAR_START_MONTH` and `COUNT_START_MONTH` are the same?  Is `YEAR1_MONTHS` supposed to be 12?

Answer (score 0):

```
--Test table.
CREATE TABLE #CalTest (
    ExampleNumber SMALLINT IDENTITY,
    FiscalYearStartMonth SMALLINT,
    CountStartMonth SMALLINT,
    TotalMonths SMALLINT,
    Year1Months SMALLINT,
    Year2Months SMALLINT,
    Year3Months SMALLINT,
    Year4Months SMALLINT,
    Year5Months SMALLINT,
    Year6Months SMALLINT,
    Leftover SMALLINT,
)
GO

--Sample data as per the OP.
INSERT INTO #CalTest (FiscalYearStartMonth, CountStartMonth, TotalMonths, Year1Months, Year2Months, Year3Months, Year4Months, Year5Months, Year6Months, Leftover)
VALUES
    (7,9,36,4,12,12,8,0,0,0),
    (7,5,14,8,6,0,0,0,0,0)
GO

SELECT * FROM #CalTest 
GO

CREATE FUNCTION guest.PickMin
--This function simply picks the smaller of two numbers.
(
    @FirstSmallInt SMALLINT,
    @SecondSmallInt SMALLINT
)
RETURNS SMALLINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RetVal SMALLINT

    IF @FirstSmallInt < @SecondSmallInt 
        SET @RetVal = @FirstSmallInt
    ELSE 
        SET @RetVal = @SecondSmallInt

    RETURN @RetVal
END
GO

;WITH CTE AS
(
    --Calculations for Year 1.
    SELECT 
        c.ExampleNumber, c.FiscalYearStartMonth, c.CountStartMonth, 1 AS YearNumber, c.TotalMonths,

        CASE
            WHEN c.CountStartMonth > c.FiscalYearStartMonth THEN
                guest.PickMin( 12 - (c.CountStartMonth - c.FiscalYearStartMonth), c.TotalMonths ) 
            ELSE
                c.FiscalYearStartMonth - c.CountStartMonth
        END AS Year1Months,

        --These are placeholders for Year2 - Year6.
        CAST(NULL AS SMALLINT) AS Year2Months, CAST(NULL AS SMALLINT) AS Year3Months, CAST(NULL AS SMALLINT) AS Year4Months, CAST(NULL AS SMALLINT) AS Year5Months, CAST(NULL AS SMALLINT) AS Year6Months,

        --Calculate the left over months.
        c.TotalMonths - guest.PickMin( 
            CASE
                WHEN c.CountStartMonth > c.FiscalYearStartMonth THEN
                    guest.PickMin( 12 - (c.CountStartMonth - c.FiscalYearStartMonth), c.TotalMonths ) 
                ELSE
                    c.FiscalYearStartMonth - c.CountStartMonth
            END, 
            c.TotalMonths 
            ) AS Leftover
    FROM #CalTest c

    UNION ALL
        --Calculations for Year 2
        SELECT 
        c2.ExampleNumber, c2.FiscalYearStartMonth, c2.CountStartMonth, c2.YearNumber + 1, c2.TotalMonths,
        NULL, guest.PickMin(12, c2.Leftover), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        c2.Leftover - guest.PickMin( 12, c2.Leftover)
    FROM CTE c2
    WHERE c2.YearNumber = 1

    UNION ALL
        --Calculations for Year 3
        SELECT 
        c2.ExampleNumber, c2.FiscalYearStartMonth, c2.CountStartMonth, c2.YearNumber + 1, c2.TotalMonths,
        NULL, NULL, guest.PickMin(12, c2.Leftover), NULL, NULL, NULL,
        c2.Leftover - guest.PickMin( 12, c2.Leftover)
    FROM CTE c2
    WHERE c2.YearNumber = 2

    UNION ALL
        --Calculations for Year 4
        SELECT 
        c2.ExampleNumber, c2.FiscalYearStartMonth, c2.CountStartMonth, c2.YearNumber + 1, c2.TotalMonths,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, guest.PickMin(12, c2.Leftover), NULL, NULL,
        c2.Leftover - guest.PickMin( 12, c2.Leftover)
    FROM CTE c2
    WHERE c2.YearNumber = 3

    UNION ALL
        --Calculations for Year 5
        SELECT 
        c2.ExampleNumber, c2.FiscalYearStartMonth, c2.CountStartMonth, c2.YearNumber + 1, c2.TotalMonths,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, guest.PickMin(12, c2.Leftover), NULL,
        c2.Leftover - guest.PickMin( 12, c2.Leftover)
    FROM CTE c2
    WHERE c2.YearNumber = 4

    UNION ALL
        --Calculations for Year 6
        SELECT 
        c2.ExampleNumber, c2.FiscalYearStartMonth, c2.CountStartMonth, c2.YearNumber + 1, c2.TotalMonths,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, guest.PickMin(12, c2.Leftover), 
        c2.Leftover - guest.PickMin( 12, c2.Leftover)
    FROM CTE c2
    WHERE c2.YearNumber = 5
)
SELECT 
    --Comment out the next line if you don't want it in your output.
    ExampleNumber, FiscalYearStartMonth, CountStartMonth, TotalMonths,

    --These are the output columns the OP asked for.
    --SUM() will exclude the NULL values used as placeholders in the above CTE.
    SUM(Year1Months) Year1Months,
    SUM(Year2Months) Year2Months,
    SUM(Year3Months) Year3Months,
    SUM(Year4Months) Year4Months,
    SUM(Year5Months) Year5Months,
    SUM(Year6Months) Year6Months,
    MIN(Leftover) Leftover
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ExampleNumber, FiscalYearStartMonth, CountStartMonth, TotalMonths
ORDER BY ExampleNumber

--Drop as needed.
DROP FUNCTION guest.PickMin
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CASE
    WHEN month( getdate() ) < 7 then year( getdate()) 
        ELSE year( getdate() ) + 1
    END as FY
    , CASE
    WHEN month( getdate() ) > 6 then ABS(MONTH(getdate())-6)
        ELSE MONTH(getdate())+6
    END as Fiscal_month
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select 1 sn, DATENAME(mm,Getdate())+', '+ convert(Varchar(50),Year(Getdate())) Display, DateAdd(mm,DateDiff(mm,0,getdate())-0,0) [From], dateadd(day, 0 - day(dateadd(month, 1 , getdate())), dateadd(month, 1 , getdate())) [To]

Union

Select 2 sn, DATENAME(mm,dateadd (mm, -1,getdate()))+', '+ convert(Varchar(50), Year(dateadd (mm, -1,getdate()))) Display, DateAdd(mm,DateDiff(mm,0,dateadd (mm, -1,getdate()))-0,0) [From], dateadd(day, 0 - day(dateadd(month, 1 ,dateadd (mm, -1,getdate()))), dateadd(month, 1 ,dateadd (mm, -1,getdate()))) [To]

Union

Select 3 sn, DATENAME(mm,dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -1,getdate())))+', '+ convert(Varchar(50), Year(dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -1,getdate())))) Display, DateAdd(mm,DateDiff(mm,0,dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -1,getdate())))-0,0) [From], dateadd(day, 0 - day(dateadd(month, 1 ,dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -1,getdate())))), dateadd(month, 1 ,dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -1,getdate())))) [To]

Union
/* ---- Continu ---------------------- */

Select 11 sn, DATENAME(mm,dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -9,getdate())))+', '+ convert(Varchar(50), Year(dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -9,getdate())))) Display, DateAdd(mm,DateDiff(mm,0,dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -9,getdate())))-0,0) [From], dateadd(day, 0 - day(dateadd(month, 1 ,dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -9,getdate())))), dateadd(month, 1 ,dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -9,getdate())))) [To] 

Union 

Select 12 sn, DATENAME(mm,dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -10,getdate())))+', '+ convert(Varchar(50), Year(dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -10,getdate())))) Display, DateAdd(mm,DateDiff(mm,0,dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -10,getdate())))-0,0) [From], dateadd(day, 0 - day(dateadd(month, 1 ,dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -10,getdate())))), dateadd(month, 1 ,dateadd (mm, -1,dateadd (mm, -10,getdate())))) [To] Order By sn
```